# button return false when click PHP

Tags: php, button, click, isset

i have multiple buttons that create according the amount of data in database. Here's the code

```
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from barang");
  while (($data = mysql_fetch_row($sql))!=null)
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src=\" ". $data[4]  . "\"height=\"100\"></td>";
    echo "<td> $data[1] </td>";
    echo "<td> $data[2] </td>";
    echo "<td>" . uang($data[3]) . "</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"$data[0]\" id=\"button\" value=\"Buy\" OnClick=\"checkBtn(event)\"/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $cek[] = $data[0];
   }
   unset($data);
   ?>
```

And below is the code to find out which button was clicked.

```
        for ($x=0; $x<=(count($cek) - 1); $x++)
        {

            echo $cek[$x];

            $value = isset($_POST[$cek[$x]]);
            var_dump($value);

            if (isset($_POST[$cek[$x]])) 
            {
                $values = $cek[$x];
                //echo $values;
                echo "testing";
            }
            //echo $values;
        }
        var_dump($values);
        if ($values != "")
        {
            $_SESSION['item'] = $values;
            header("location:confirm.php");
        }
        unset ($cek, $value);
      ?>
```

The problem is, the return value of the clicked button always false whenever i try to click the buttons.
i've been tracing this code for hours and can't find the problem, any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Your problem is that the button is never actually submitted, regardless of what you try to name it. Create a input type='hidden' field, with the name as something standardized and the value as data[0]. Then simply retrieve the particular name and check its value?

Comment: how to retrieve the value if we the name of the input hidden field is all the same?